# Release WSL 1 imported distro space after unregistering it

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Scenario

I installed some extra **WSL 1 instances** using `wsl --import <my instance name> <destination folder> <image.tar.gz> --version 1`. I want to free up space, so I decided to uninstall some of them.

*I do not have admin access on my computer.*

#### Approach

I ran `wsl --unregister <my instance name>` in the command line, which took a few minutes to run. I noticed that in `destination folder` all left was a temp folder, empty. Anyway, I also deleted the `destination folder` where the image file system was originally stored.

#### Problem

The disk usage did not decrease. **Surprisingly, it increased instead.**

#### What have I tried

- My Disk has 1TB total. On the disk properties (right click C: on windows exporer -> Properties), it says there is 800GB used. [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) tells me 600GB of my disk is used, which makes me suspicious about this 200GB that windirstat can't see.
- I could not find this missing dead data in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages` (also, this folder is only 10GB)
- I searched the disk for `*.vhdx` files and found nothing.